Dedekind eta and Lie algebras
Reference request and a formal question
I am currently self-studying modular forms and read the Wikipedia page for Dedekind's eta function. There it reads that: "The theory of the algebraic characters of the affine Lie algebras gives rise to a large class of previously unknown identities for the eta function".
Q1: I know the basics of modular forms and their transformations. I also know the basic definitions of a Lie algebra and how it works. What I am interested in is how to connect these two. I would love to see some examples. Could it have something to do with the Weyl-Kac character formula?
EDIT 1:
I know some details about the Macdonald's identities where the simplest representation comes from the affine Lie algebra of type $A_1$ which gives the JTP (and the easiest example to show):
$$\prod\limits_{n={1}}^{\infty}({1-q^{2n}})({1+q^{2n-1}z^n})({1+q^{2n-1}z^{-n}})=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{q^{m^2}}{z^m}$$
Which can be connected to the Dedekind eta through it's connection to the Euler function and realizing the connections to, for example, Ramanujan's g-invariants.
Q2: In this post you can see a Macdonald's identity for $\mathfrak{sl_5}$.
I would like to see other examples and request references of helpful literature.
Q1 and Q2 are closely related which is why I would like to keep them in the same post.
